# Why does my monitor keep erroneously exiting power save mode?

Tags: windows-10, display, powersave

The internet is absolutely rife with people complaining that their monitors keep erroneously entering power save mode or that their monitors are stuck in power save mode, but if Google is any indication, I'm the first person on Earth to run into a monitor erroneously *exiting* power save mode.

Whenever my monitor goes into power save mode, for some reason, after a short, unpredictable period of time -- sometimes it's a few seconds, sometimes it's 20 minutes -- it just turns back on for no reason. It's not because I touched my keyboard, it's not because I touched my mouse, it's not because I'm really, really fat and just happened to make my desk shake enough to move the mouse while walking by like the T-Rex in Jurassic Park... it just does it on its own, and it doesn't make a lick of sense.

- I've tried another monitor and it did the same thing, so it's not the monitor
- I've tried connecting the monitor via HDMI instead of DVI and it did the same thing, so it's not the connection
- I've tried terminating all processes in Task Manager except those under the "Windows processes" header and it did the same thing, so it's not a misbehaving program
- I've tried disabling "Allow this device to wake the computer" for all devices in Device Manager and it did the same thing, but I believe this setting only affects sleep mode
- I've tried `powercfg -waketimers`, but there aren't any wake timers on this PC, and again, I believe that's only relevant to sleep mode

This is a problem I've had for as long as I can remember, but have never been able to solve. The obvious workaround, of course, is to just turn the monitor off by hand, but I've been getting into home automation recently and now need to find a proper solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: The only thing you probably haven't done is unplug the mouse and keyboard. So, the monitor sleep mode is controlled by the computer. It can't be a monitor problem, or cable problem. It is your computer thinking there is activity. And because the most likely activity that brings the computer out of power save mode is mouse or keyboard activity, then that is what you should try to unhook for a while. It's probably the mouse sending stray signals to the computer.

Comment: I'll second that. Over-sensitive mice do this all the time. (Nope, you're not the first person to run into this! :] )

Comment: This didn't even occur to me as the issue has persisted through at least three different keyboard and mouse combos, but apparently this is the answer. If both keyboard and mouse are unplugged completely, my monitor remains off indefinitely, for all the good that does me with my automation problem.